# Reuse saga logic

Tags: redux, redux-saga

We have a general Form component, whith an accompanying saga to handle validation and submission

```
function* validateAndSubmit(action) {
    const errors = clientSideValidate(action.values);
    if (errors) {
        return yield put({type: SUBMIT_FAILED, formKey: action.formKey, errors: errors});
    }

    try {
        const response = yield call(submitToTargetUrl(action.values, action.url));
        if (response.errors) {
            return yield put({type: SUBMIT_FAILED, formKey: action.formKey, errors: response.errors});
        }

        yield put({type: SUBMIT_SUCCESS, formKey: action.formKey});
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: SUBMIT_FAILED, formKey: action.formKey, errors: [e.message]});
    }
}

function* form() {
    yield takeEvery(SUBMITTED, validateAndSubmit);
}
```

Now, we have another component, say `UserForm` that wraps the general Form component. On submission, we want to Submit the form to the backend and fetch some data from an external API concurrently, wait for both to complete, and then dispatch some action. This logic will live in another Saga in some other file. What would be the right pattern for reusing the `validateAndSubmit` logic? Is there some way to do this:

```
function* handleUserFormSubmit(action) {
    const [submitResult, fetchResult] = yield all([
        call(validateAndSubmitSaga),
        call(fetchOtherData),
    ]);

    // ...test for successful results for both

    if (allIsGood) {
        yield put({type: ALL_IS_GOOD});
    }
}

function* userForm() {
    yield takeEvery(USER_FORM_SUBMITTED, handleUserFormSubmit);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with a slightly different solution. Instead of `call`-ing we're `take`-ing:

```
function* handleUserFormSubmit(action) {
    const [submitResult, fetchResult] = yield all([
        yield take(SUBMIT_SUCCESS),
        yield take(FETCH_OTHER_DATA_SUCCESS),
    ]);

    // ...test for successful results for both

    if (allIsGood) {
        yield put({type: ALL_IS_GOOD});
    }
}

function* userForm() {
    yield takeEvery(USER_FORM_SUBMITTED, handleUserFormSubmit);
}
```

This way the other Saga can do its thing undisturbed, an this saga can React according to its own logic

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a reusable `validateAndSubmit` function that would handle the validation and submission, then would return an error if any. And then, have a form submit saga effect that uses this function.

```
async function reusableValidateAndSubmit(formValues, submitUrl) {
  try {
    const errors = clientSideValidate(formValues);
    if (errors) {
      return errors;
    }

    const response = await submitToTargetUrl(formValues, submitUrl);
    if (response.errors) {
      return response.errors;
    }

    return null;

  } catch (e) {
    console.error('@reusableValidateAndSubmit: ', e);
    return [e.message];
  }
}


function* handleFormSubmitSaga(action) {
  try {
    const { values, url, formKey } = action;
    const errors = yield call(reusableValidateAndSubmit, values, url);

    if (errors) {
      return yield put({type: SUBMIT_FAILED, formKey: formKey, errors: errors});
    }

    return yield put({type: SUBMIT_SUCCESS, formKey: formKey});  

  } catch (e) {
    return yield put({type: SUBMIT_FAILED, formKey: action.formKey, errors: [e.message]});
  }
}


function* form() {
  yield takeEvery(SUBMITTED, handleFormSubmitSaga);
}
```

For the `handleUserFormSubmit`, I'm not just quite sure if in your use case, you want for the `validateAndSubmitSaga` to fail if `fetchOtherData` fails, and vice versa. Using redux-saga's all() would bring this effect as it behaves like [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

A snippet on the return value of `Promise.all()` from MDN:

> This returned promise is then resolved/rejected asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty) when all the promises in the given iterable have resolved, or if any of the promises reject.

Supposedly, it is your expected behavior, and having implemented the code above. You could just reuse `reusableValidateAndSubmit` function

```
function* handleUserFormSubmit(action) {
  const [submitError, fetchResult] = yield all([
    call(reusableValidateAndSubmit, action.values, action.url),
    call(fetchOtherData),
  ]);

  // ...test for successful results for both
  // submitError is null if submit was a success
  // fetchResult must have a value or return true if was a success
  if (!submitError && fetchResult) {
    yield put({type: ALL_IS_GOOD});
  }
}
```

May I also suggest having a look at some form frameworks that you could partner with redux (i.e. [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/)) as they could also help in some use cases.